# IF statement within this SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I'm having trouble with using an IF statement within this SQL Server query.

What I want:

```
SELECT *

  IF(ProgramId = NULL AND BranchId = NULL AND OrganizationId = NULL) {
     --EXECUTE QUERY ONLY ON THIS CONDITION
  }
  ELSE IF(ProgramId = 68 AND BranchId = 78 AND OrganizationId = 2) {
     --EXECUTE QUERY ONLY ON THIS CONDITION
  }
  ELSE {
     --EXECUTE QUERY ONLY ON THIS CONDITION
  }
FROM 
   [dbo].[UserMenu]
```

This is my C# code logic can you please transfer it to SQL

```
if (organization == null && program == null && branch == null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization == null && program == null && branch != null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization == null && program != null && branch != null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization == null && program != null && branch == null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization != null && program != null && branch != null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization != null && program == null && branch == null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization != null && program == null && branch != null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
else if (organization != null && program != null && branch == null)
{
    /*retrieve usermenu table data*/
}
```

Please help me to sort it out.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the difference in the queries to be executed?

Comment: Your Question is not very clear

Comment: Actually it's a small part of my query.There are eight condition that may arise based on some criteria from my view end. It's hard to describe so i escape it.

Comment: @Taskin What you want from these these conditions ? do you want to select data or something else?

Comment: yes i want to select data

Comment: Are ProgramId, BranchId columns from [dbo].[UserMenu] table or are they variables? Clarify your question.

Comment: ProgramId, BranchId OrganizationId are columns from [dbo].[UserMenu]

Comment: Are the parameters `organization, program and branch` optional parameters supplied by the user. If so, do you want the query to ignore one or more filters if the user does not provide a value for one of these 3 fields. e.g. if `branch = null, organisation = 3 and program = 5` would find all rows with these organisations and programs, but the filter on branch would not be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want order your results by those conditions and if several conditions match then just pick first matched. If so then you can do it like:

```
create table t(ID int, A int, B int)

insert into t values
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, null),
(1, null, null),
(2, 2, 1)


select ID, A, B from (select *,
row_number() over (partition by ID order by 
case when A = 1 and B =1 then 1 
 when A = 1 and B is null then 2
 when A is null and B is null then 3 
else 4 end )as rn
from t
)t where rn = 1
```

Output:

```
ID  A   B
1   1   1
2   2   1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3433f/4)

**EDIT1**

After edit of question I understand the problem as:
Pass variables to your stored proc or whatever you use:

```
Declare @ProgramID int,
Declare @BranchID int,
Declare @OrganizationID int


SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[UserMenu]
WHERE (ProgramID = @ProgramID OR @ProgramID IS NULL) AND 
(BranchID = @BranchID OR @BranchID IS NULL) AND 
(OrganizationID = @OrganizationID OR @OrganizationID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have to select data based on if condition.How can i achieve that.
Is it possible like
    case when A = 1 and B =1 then Select * from sometable

Comment: We are all suggesting here. Don't you think you should clarify in more details what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem Correctly you should do something like this

```
Declare @Programid int,
Declare @BranchId int,
Declare @OrganizationId int

SELECT @Programid=ProgramId, @BranchId=BranchId,@OrganizationId = OrganizationId
             FROM [dbo].[UserMenu] 

  IF (@ProgramId=NULL AND @BranchId=NULL AND @OrganizationId=NULL)

 BEGIN

 /* your if condition code goes here*/
 END

ELSE IF(@ProgramId=68 AND @BranchId=78 AND @OrganizationId=2)

 BEGIN
  /* your else if condition code goes here*/
 END

ELSE 

 BEGIN
  /* your else condition code goes here*/
 END
```

Comment: nothing actually i meant to execute it by specific condition only.